# Can't load my custom module in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, module, sinatra

I am trying to load my custom module in Sinatra but when loading the app I get

```
'include' : Wrong argument type String (expected Module)
```

So in my app.rb I have

```
require './config/config.rb'
include 'MyConfig'
```

and my Module looks like so

```
module MyConfig
def config
 environment = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development" 
 YAML.load_file("/config/config.yml")[environment]
end
end
```

I am trying to use the config.yml file to load some variables (i.e email credentials).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [Sinatra Config file](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-contrib/1.3.2/frames).

Answer (score 3):

include is not like require.  Include must be part of another class or Module body.

Do this:

```
require './config/config.rb'

class App
    include MyConfig

    # more code here
end
```

Include basically functions as an inline extension of the class or module that is currently in scope.  It allows you to mix functionality into objects from external code without extending that external code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, not quite sure i understand it at present but will do some more reading, seems to work ok... thanks

Comment: may have jumped the gun there, am i expecting to see the config.rb file load in the console, as in it tells me its initializing/loading? as i am getting a SMTP error when sending an email but credentials are correct